# gitlab push rule,allow one specific file gradle-wrapper.jar

Tags: gitlab

As per developer requirement, I want to allow or whitelist one specific file
in push rule. Please do let me know, I am unable to find an option for a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [GitLab push rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html) (starter edition and more) does not have whitelists, you might need to fallback to a workaround like:

- restrict by commit message (if your file has the right commit message, it will be allowed)
- [open an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/infrastructure/issues), requesting that feature to be considered and implemented